# How deep are standard female pin headers?

Tags: connector, pins, header

I have a couple pcbs that will mate together with pin headers. I will have a 15mm standoff to separate these 2 boards. In my research it looks like the female pin header sockets seem to be about the same size and the male headers vary in length. I've looked at multiple female pin header spec sheets, but I haven't seen any that tell me how deep I can push in a male pin or how deep into the socket I need to push the pin in order to make a connection. I'm just trying to size my male header correctly.

Does anyone know? Or can you point me to a spec where you've seen that before?

Comment: Samtec datasheets should say

Comment: The ones I have seen don't specify. If you find a datasheet could you link to it.

Comment: suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/ssw_th.pdf

Comment: Ok great. That one has an insertion depth spec on it. That's what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: What is "standard" in your opinion? There are literally hundreds of pin headers/sockets on every supplier's site. There are square, round and blade pins of different length. There are female sockets with through hole, SMD and bottom entry options, not counting low height that almost flat on top but stick out on the other side. Even if under "standard" you mean "cheap sockets sold in hobby stores with 10x markup" you still have several options

Answer (score 1):

the ones I have here are 10.5mm board-to-board when mated to a standard pin (pin 8mm tall above board) so 8.1mm for the header body and 2.4mm for the pin strip.

this can be stretched to about 13mm before they let go. so for a 15mm gap you want a header than finishes between 10 and 12.5 mm above the board.

or you could use and ordinary male header and use a female header with long pins.

Answer (score 1):

So it does look like Samtec has an intsertion depth spec on their headers. See http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/ssw_th.pdf

Insertion Depth: (3.68 mm) .145" to(6.35 mm) .250"

That's what I was looking for. Thanks @DKNguyen